# Magento 2 Migration Tool Integrity constraint violation

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

I'm getting the following error using the Magento 2 *Migration Tool* 2.3.0 during the Map Step:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '0--0-*-0.0000-0.0000-0-*' for key
>   'UNQ_D2BA9F275EE0D3F3C26A1EC39FD4924D'

I have searched on Google for this error but cannot find anything similar. How can I find where this is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

It happens for either one of these following reasons,

**Reason 1 :**

This will cause if you accidentally delete default attribute set in that case.

1.Truncate the following table eav_attribute_group,eav_attribute_set(Disable Foreign key constrain)
2.Insert the table

> INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`, `entity_type_id`,
>   `attribute_set_name`, `sort_order`) VALUES (1, 1, 'Default', 2),(2, 2,
>   'Default', 2),(3, 3, 'Default', 1),(4, 4, 'Default', 1),(5, 5,
>   'Default', 1),(6, 6,'Default', 1),(7, 7, 'Default', 1),(8, 8,
>   'Default', 1),(10, 10, 'Default', 1);

then

> INSERT INTO `eav_attribute_group` (`attribute_group_id`,
>   `attribute_set_id`, `attribute_group_name`, `sort_order`,
>   `default_id`, `attribute_group_code`, `tab_group_code`) VALUES (1, 1,
>   'General', 1, 1, 'general', NULL),(4, 2, 'General', 1, 1, 'general',
>   NULL),(7, 3, 'General', 10, 1, 'general', NULL),(10, 3, 'General
>   Information', 2, 0,'general-information', NULL),(13, 3, 'Display
>   Settings', 20, 0, 'display-settings', NULL),(16, 3, 'Custom Design',
>   30, 0, 'custom-design', NULL),(19, 4, 'Product Details', 10, 1,
>   'product-details', 'basic'),(22, 4, 'Advanced Pricing', 40, 0,
>   'advanced-pricing', 'advanced'),(25, 4, 'Search Engine Optimization',
>   30, 0, 'search-engine-optimization', 'basic'),(28, 4, 'Images', 20, 0,
>   'image-management', 'basic'),(31, 4, 'Design', 50, 0, 'design',
>   'advanced'),(34, 4, 'Autosettings', 60, 0, 'autosettings',
>   'advanced'),(37, 4, 'Content', 15, 0, 'content', 'basic'),(40, 4,
>   'Schedule Design Update',55, 0, 'schedule-design-update',
>   'advanced'),(43, 4, 'Bundle Items', 16, 0, 'bundle-items', NULL),(46,
>   5, 'General', 1, 1, 'general', NULL),(49, 6, 'General', 1, 1,
>   'general', NULL),(52, 7, 'General', 1, 1, 'general', NULL),(55, 8,
>   'General', 1, 1, 'general', NULL),(58, 4, 'Gift Options', 61, 0,
>   'gift-options', NULL),(61, 10, 'General', 1, 1, 'general', NULL);

**Reason 2 :**

It happens may be you have migrated data over existing data in it, please try migrate data with fresh database with each try. Even if the migration failed once you have to start migrate in fresh database.

**EDIT :**

Once the migration is failed then you have to fix and start migration from new database. Just follow below steps to make it easier.

1. Install a fresh magento.
2. Take a backup of fresh database then start migrate.
3. Once failed fix it and import the backup database then start migrate again.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: but in magento 1 table all entry available

Comment: Either one of these reason  cause problem in your case

Comment: It seems duplicate entry happened so the migration failed there, try the above steps or start migration in new database.

Comment: i have allready duplicate entry removed it and no need to new database installed it

Comment: If you truncated the complete table then there won't be any problem if issue still persist then it must be data is not been truncated. So gotta go with fresh migration.

Comment: which table i will truncate?

Comment: Look at the issue it stopped at eav setup so it must eav tables

Comment: i have allready try yesterday

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, is it compulsory to start with new database? because its too time taking process to initiate.

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, everytime do we need to install magento2 fresh package?

Comment: See EDIT answer @jafarpinjar

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, yes started migration from fresh database, same error again, already started with new db, then how that error will come and how that will resolve if fresh db used

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, what need to do to fix that error? 
Duplicate entry '1-Migration_Default' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME'

Comment: Fresh database won't fix the issue mate, you have to fix it then start it fresh db @jafarpinjar

Comment: Yes, any fix done on this? its not working for me even with the fresh database

Comment: Oke I finally found it, It is caused by the TIG PostNL plugin on Magento 2.