# Data Migration > Eav step error

Tags: magento2.3, data-migration

**Data Migration > EAV Step**

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-Migration_Default' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME'

i have find solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92578/data-migration-eav-step-error) but not work for me also **i have remove duplicate attribute set in eav_attribute_set table**

but after run command then new error genrated

> Undefined offset: 4 in
> vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on
> line 292

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264085/magento-2-migration-tool-integrity-constraint-violation

Comment: not working for me

Comment: Please remove the database and once again execute data migration command with fresh database.

Comment: i have tried this but still not work for me

Comment: Check into your Magento 2 database. Is there any same attribute set as Magento 1?

Comment: i have try to default attribute is same and removed it but still same error showing

Comment: try to migration on fresh database

Comment: Not working I have tried this

Comment: @RakeshDonga, have you resolved this error? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @jafarpinjar no.........

Comment: @RakeshDonga, what u did after getting this error?

Comment: @RkRathod, even with fresh database its not working, any fixes?

Comment: any error accour????

Answer (score 2):

This error comes when we run migration command 2nd time on same database. kindly remove the database and again use fresh database and then do all the setting. Run migration command .